# Implications of adding NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription into info.plist

Tags: ios, info.plist, location-services

does anyone know the implications of adding `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` on the `info.plist` file? We got rejected by what it looks like a new automatic check that looks for specific calls to certain APIs that require special permissions. Unfortunately, we are using a library that has a reference to `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and although we are not using it we are being rejected for not specifying the reason on the info.plist. Of course I could add it to pass certification, but would there be any negative implications?

Comment: Apple just wants the developer to tell the end user in their own words what location services are being used and why so that it's presented to the user in an alert window that the user must take action on. This is a "contract" between the developer and the user. The only negative implication I can see is a user experience one and whether your users will consider it an encroachment or not worth accepting given what service your app provides.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be if your app doesn't actually request the 'always' authorization.  We ran into the same issue this week as well.   Looks like Apple is finally enforcing the [requirements](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization?language=objc).   I also added `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` in case they start enforcing that as well.   I'm hoping the requirement for `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` will not be enforced once we flip our app to support only iOS 11+ next year since it's only required for iOS 10 and earlier.